# In what space is a closed set is not or not necessarily $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, real-numbers

We know that [A closed set in a metric space is $G_\delta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317479/a-closed-set-in-a-metric-space-is-g-delta)

Is there any topological space where a closed set is not necessarily $G_\delta$?

I am thinking a space where singletons are well known to be closed, but cannot be represented as countable intersection of open sets.

Comment: I think something like the double origin line ($\Bbb R\cup\{0^*\}$) would suffice. Roughly speaking, any open set containing either $0$ or $0^*$ must contain the other, while the remaining topology is what you would expect. However, $\{0\}$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Example:** The [Sierpiński space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space#Definition_and_fundamental_properties) $S=\{0,1\}$ with open sets $S,\ \emptyset,\ \{1\}.$ The set $\{0\}$ is closed but is not the intersection of any number of open sets.

**Example:** An uncountable set with the [cofinite topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofiniteness#Cofinite_topology), i.e., the open sets are the cofinite sets and the empty set. Points are closed but are not $G_\delta$-sets. Of course this is not a Hausdorff space.

**Example:** The product of uncountably many compact Hausdorff spaces, each having at least two points. This is a compact Hausdorff space, and single points are not $G_\delta$-sets.

Comment: I like the last one.  Similarly, points in the Stone-Cech remainder of a non-compact space are not $G_\delta$.

Comment: In your second example, points are closed because $\{x\}^c$ is co-finite and they are not $G_\delta$ since countable intersection of co-finite/infinite set is not finite, correct? Thanks

Comment: @Lookbehindyou A related question which may be of interest: If every closed subset of $X$ is a $G_\delta$, then is $X$ metrizable?

Comment: @Lookbehindyou A countable union of finite sets is countable, so a countable intersection of cofinite sets is cocountable.

Comment: @ForeverMozart In a countable T$_1$-space, ***every*** subset is a $G_\delta,$ and it's easy to give examples of such spaces which are not first-countable, therefore not metrizable.

Comment: @bof ah, ok so maybe I need more assumptions.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Helly space is compact Hausdorff separable perfectly normal (i.e. normal and every closed set is a $G_\delta$) but not metrisable. The Sorgenfrey line (lower limit topology) is a non-compact example.