# In a Locally Compact Hausdorff and second countable space every compact subset is a $G_\delta$ set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a second countable LCH (Locally Compact Hausdorff) then every compact subset of $X$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set.

> A set $E$ is $G_{\delta}$ if is a countable intersection of open sets.

I have two questions,

1. How to prove this result,
2. I am also wondering if that would be true for the closed sets in this space, or what would be necessary to be true for closed sets.

**Edit:**

I posted a resolution, which I found very interesting, of question 1.

Comment: Follow these: [Locally compact Hausdorff space is regular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313688/show-that-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-is-regular) $\longrightarrow$ [A topological space is separable and metrizable if and only if it is regular, Hausdorff and second-countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrizable_space#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20a%20compact%20Hausdorff,to%20the%20non%2Dseparable%20case) $\longrightarrow$  [A closed set in a metric space is  $G_δ$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317479/a-closed-set-in-a-metric-space-is-g-delta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable base for the topology of $X$, and let $K\subseteq X$ be a compact. We have that $X$ is Hausdorff, so for each $x\in K^c$ and $y\in K$, there is an open $U_{xy}$ such that $y\in U_{xy}$ but $x\notin U_{xy}$. Moreover, there exists $V_xy \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $y\in V_{xy}\subseteq U_{xy}$

Since $K$ is compact, for each $x\in K^c$ there is a finite set $Y_x \subseteq K$ such that,

$$K\subseteq \bigcup_{y\in Y_x} V_{xy} \qquad (*)$$

We have,

$$K=\bigcap_{x\in K^c}\left(\,\bigcup_{y\in Y_x}V_{xy} \right)$$
since $x\notin V_{xy}$ for all $x\in K^c$ and $y\in Y_x$.

Since the set,
$$\left\{ \bigcup_{U\in \mathcal{A}} U : \mathcal{A}\subseteq \mathcal{B} \text{ is finite}\right\}$$

is a countable collection of open sets, to demonstrate this, just prove that [the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/200390/680679).

Therefore the intersection in **(*)** is countable, because, although the intersection is indexed by a possible uncontable quantity, there is only an countable number of distinct sets, by the previous result.

This shows that $K$ is $G_\delta$.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is LCH and C-II, as indicated, $K:=\alpha (X)$, the Aleksandrov (one-point) compactification is compact and metrisable. In a metric space, all closed sets are $G_\delta$ and a compact subset of $X$ is still closed in $K$. Then relativize to $X$ again.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but recommendation for you to see the following theorem
**Theorem** In a locally compact Hausdorff space, the intersection of an open set with a closed set is locally compact. Conversely, a locally compact subset  of a Hausdorff space is the intersection of an open set and a closed set.

You can find the proof Willard's book page 130.